# How to regain lost maximum health?

Tags: dont-starve-together

Upon dying in endless mode you turn into a ghost, using the jury-rigged portal to revive will reduce your maximum hp.

How can you gain back the maximum hp that you lose to the jury-rigged portal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can regain your maximum hp by using "**Booster Shots" from the "survival" tab**, which restore 20 max hp each.

Booster shots can be crafted from: **8 rot**, **a stinger** and **2 nitre** (recipe recently changed).

So keep an eye out for bees, rocks and spoiled food if you want to make some booster shots.